# How to remove the last child of an angular element

Tags: javascript, angular

I get one angular element, and want to remove the last element and append a new one. I know I can use append to create a new one child, but how can I remove the last element. Thanks

Comment: Not acceptable from experienced user posting question without code.

Comment: What do you mean by angular element?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by "angular element" is an array element, then you can use [Splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example) method:

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

And you can use this syntax:

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
```

So the code will be like:

```
var newElement = "newElement";
var array = ["element1", "element2", "element3"];
array.splice(array.length-1, 0, newElement);
// output will be ["element1", "element2", "newElement"]
```